# Update Visual Studio Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, feature

Trying to update Sharepoint 2013 Visual Studio Workflow with feature upgarde process. Feature upgarde goes well, but no changes are apllied. I can still deploy WF from Vusual Studio 2013 and it redeploys new version without error. But I need to update WF by feature so all running workflows keep going. Any ideas?